# How to reduce memory usage of a flatMap method which running out of memory due to many data to process

Tags: javascript, node.js, out-of-memory

In my NodeJS API, I have to process a lot of data and calculations.
The following method is failing with an error as the `out of memory error`.

```
const allInputs = days
    .flatMap(day => {
      const isoDay = day.toISOString();
      return sites.map(site => {
        const { studyId, siteId } = site;
        const data = {
          staleCandidates: getStaleCandidatesFromData({
            data: analyticsData,
            site,
            day,
            noContact: studyGoals?.inactive?.rules?.noContact,
          }),
          ...replayData.find(x => x.day === isoDay && x.studyId === studyId && x.siteId === siteId),
        };
        const calculator = new SiteScoreCalculator({ site, studyGoals, data, day });
        return siteToInput({ days: [day], site, calculator });
      });
    })
    .filter(removeNullScores);
```

The `allInputs` is passed later to another method which in the end saves the data to DB via a mutation to one service.

During the process, the method stuck with the error I explained before and I don't know how to optimize it for data like '12000' items circa.

I would like to make it in smaller batches/chunks and reduce the memory spikes.

I'm sharing the full method as ref

```
import logger from '@trialbee/logger';
import fetchStudyGoals from '../../projectGoals';
import { getAnalyticsSiteScoreReplayData, saveSiteScore } from '../../requests/analytics';
import { splitListToBatches } from '../../utils/batches';
import { getStaleCandidatesFromData, removeNullScores, siteToInput } from '../../utils/site';
import { daysFromInterval } from '../../utils/times';
import SiteScoreCalculator from '../site/SiteScoreCalculator';

const log = logger();

const studiesToSites = studies =>
  studies.flatMap(({ studyId, siteIds }) => siteIds.map(siteId => ({ studyId, siteId })));

async function replaySiteScores({ interval, studies, prune, data: analyticsData }) {
  const start = Date.now();
  log.debug('Replay site scores start');

  const days = daysFromInterval(interval);
  const sites = studiesToSites(studies);
  const [studyGoals, replayData] = await Promise.all([
    fetchStudyGoals(),
    getAnalyticsSiteScoreReplayData({ interval, studies }),
  ]);

  const allInputs = days
    .flatMap(day => {
      const isoDay = day.toISOString();
      return sites.map(site => {
        const { studyId, siteId } = site;
        const data = {
          staleCandidates: getStaleCandidatesFromData({
            data: analyticsData,
            site,
            day,
            noContact: studyGoals?.inactive?.rules?.noContact,
          }),
          ...replayData.find(x => x.day === isoDay && x.studyId === studyId && x.siteId === siteId),
        };
        const calculator = new SiteScoreCalculator({ site, studyGoals, data, day });
        return siteToInput({ days: [day], site, calculator });
      });
    })
    .filter(removeNullScores);

  const batches = splitListToBatches(allInputs);
  await batches.reduce(
    (previousPromise, input, index) =>
      previousPromise.then(async () => {
        const cnt = await saveSiteScore({ input, prune: index === 0 ? prune : null });
        log.debug('Replay site score batch %d of %d (%d data points) saved', index + 1, batches.length, cnt);
      }),
    Promise.resolve()
  );

  log.info('Replay site scores completed in %ds', (Date.now() - start) / 1e3);
}

export default replaySiteScores;
```

Comment: 12,000 items doesn't seem like it should cause a memory problem, you'd need millions of large objects. Something else is going on.

Comment: But you could try filtering the null scores in the inner map instead of after the flatMap.

Comment: When this method is hit before the savings the memory goes up to 700mb circa and I have a requirement to keep it under 500mb. Not sure how to achieve that. 
for the filter I can try to move it after the map